# mapping a constant function across Array(3) vs. [1,2,3]: why are they different

Tags: javascript

Why do these 2 expressions produce different results?

```
> [1,3,4].map(x=>5) // (3) [5, 5, 5]
> Array(3).map(x=>5) // (3) [empty × 3]
```

Comment: [1,3,4] have content in all the three indices whereas Array(3) produces only empty valued array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the arrays are different. `[1, 3, 4]` creates an array with a `length` of 3 and three entries in it. `Array(3)` creates an array with a `length` of 3 with **no** entries in it (a *sparse* array). `map` skips over empty slots in arrays, so your `map` callback is never executed.

You can see that here, where the first has a property called `"0"` (remember that standard arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)¹, barring optimization in the JavaScript engine) but the second doesn't:

```js
const a1 = [1, 3, 5];
console.log(a1.length); // 3
console.log("0" in a1); // true

const a2 = Array(3);
console.log(a2.length); // 3
console.log("0" in a2); // false
```

If you want to fill that array, use [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
console.log(Array(3).fill(5));
```

`fill` is great where the same value is being used for all elements, but if you want different values for different elements, you can use the mapping callback of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
console.log(Array.from(Array(3), x => Math.random()));
```

When using `Array.from`, if the size is **large** (not just `3`), then on some JavaScript engines (such as V8 in Chrome, Edge, and others), you'd want to use `{length: value}` rather than `Array(value)`, because it's a temporary object and when you use `Array(value)`, V8 (and perhaps others) pre-allocates storage for that number of elements, even though the elements start out initially empty. So:

```js
console.log(Array.from({length: 3}, x => Math.random()));
```

---

¹ *(That's a post on my anemic litle blog.)*

Comment: Thanks, what are some use cases of sparse arrays in javascript? Matrix math in the browser....anything else?

Comment: @tjb - I'm not sure I've ever used an array when I needed it to be sparse. I usually just use an object in that case, since for my use cases where the array would be sparse didn't have need of array features like `push` or `length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [1,3,4].map(x=>5) // (3) [5, 5, 5]
```

The above can be re-written as

```
[1,3,4].map(function(x){
return 5;
})
```

Which will output [5,5,5] as it is returning 5 on every value in the array.

```js
var a=Array(3).map(x=>5)
console.log(a)
```

The above creates a new array with 3 empty slots in array. Map skips all the empty elements and thus returns undefined